# Control behaviour of df.at or df.loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

How does one control the behaviour of `df.at()` or `df.loc()` so that if there is no match against the index, a `KeyError` or `IndexError` is returned? For example:

```
import pandas as pd

index = ['A','B','C']
headers = [1,2,3,4]

df = pd.DataFrame(index=index,columns=headers)

df.at['A',1] = "Hello"
```

This updates the value at the appropriate place in the df to "Hello".  Fine.

However:

```
df.at['D',1] = "Hello"
```

The above creates a new row in the df with index "D" and puts in the value.

How do I control this so it throws an exception instead?  Can I make the index read-only for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use [Categorical Data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html). Note this will impact *any* method which attempts to add an item to the index which does not belong to the index when it was converted to Categorical.

```
df.index = pd.Series(df.index).astype('category')

# SUCCESS
df.at['C', 1] = 'Bye'

# FAIL
df.at['D', 1] = 'Hello'
```

You will find:

> **KeyError**: 'D'
>
> **TypeError**: cannot insert an item into a CategoricalIndex that is not already an existing category